# Delete rows in pandas frame that have other shape

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete rows in a pandas data frame that have another shape than (99, 13) in the 'MEL' column.

```
path    MEL  word
0   8d37d10e7f97ddea2eca9d39a4cf821b4457b041.wav    [[-10.160675, -13.804866, 0.9188097, 4.415375,...   one
1   9a8f761be3fa0d0a963f5612ba73e68cc0ad11ba.wav    [[-10.482644, -13.339122, -3.4994812, -5.29343...   one
2   314cdc39f628bc68d216498b2080bcc7a549a45f.wav    [[-11.076196, -13.980294, -17.289637, -41.0668...   one
3   cc499e63eee4a3bcca48b5b452df04990df83570.wav    [[-13.830213, -12.64104, -3.7780707, -10.76490...   one
4   38cdcc4d9432ce4a2fe63e0998dbca91e64b954a.wav    [[-11.967776, -23.27864, -10.3656, -8.786977, ...   one
```

I have tried the folowing:

```
indexNames = merged[ merged['MEL'].shape != (99,13) ].index
merged.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

The first line of code however gives me `key error: True`. Anyone an idea on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition

```
 merged['MEL'].shape != (99,13)
```

evaluates to either True or False.

Please note that you may select rows from a DataFrame using a boolean vector **the same length as the DataFrame’s index** (for example, something derived from one of the columns of the DataFrame). More here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

EDIT: This code might help

```
 # generate sample dataset
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': [np.random.rand(3,2),np.random.rand(5,2),np.random.rand(7,8),np.random.rand(5,2)], 
                              'col2': ['b','a','b','q'],
                              'col3': ['c','c','c','q'],
                              'col4': ['d','d','d','q'], 
                              'col5': ['e','e','a','q'] })

    for index in df.index:
        if df.loc[index]['col1'].shape !=(5,2):
            df.drop(index , inplace=True)
```

EDIT2: Without a loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': [np.random.rand(3,2),np.random.rand(5,2),np.random.rand(7,8),np.random.rand(5,2)], 
                          'col2': ['b','a','b','q'],
                          'col3': ['c','c','c','q'],
                          'col4': ['d','d','d','q'], 
                          'col5': ['e','e','a','q'] })
df['shapes'] = [x.shape for x in df.col1.values]
df = df[df['shapes']!=(5,2)].drop('shapes', axis = 1)
```

Comment: Allright so it is not possible what I am trying to do here? Is there maybe a way when I convert it to a np array? Or make a new column with all the values true and false in it and drop the rows from there?

Comment: To tell the truth I am a bit confused with your desired output here. Maybe a sample of your dataframe could help.

Comment: Added it to the question! The MEL column contains arrays with shape (99,13) but also arrays with other shapes. I'm trying to remove all rows that have another shape than (99,13).

Answer (score 0):

... In other words, you want all the rows where the column `'MEL'` has the shape `(99, 13)`. I would do

```
my_desired_df = merged[merged['MEL'].shape == (99,13)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a series of the shapes

```
df['MEL'].apply(lambda x: x.shape)
```

Then you can test this to get a boolean series

```
df['MEL'].apply(lambda x: x.shape) == (93,3)
```

And then index with the boolean series

```
new_df = df.loc[df['MEL'].apply(lambda x: x.shape) == (93,3), :]
```

This will give you everything that matches your shape. It's probably easier to do it this way then to play with df.drop(), but you could do that do with

```
correct = df['MEL'].apply(lambda x: x.shape) == (93,3)
new_df = df.drop(correct[~correct].index)
```